# How do I sort a list in the same order as another list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, optimization, heuristics

Let's say I have two lists with the first representing total volume and the second representing the respective unique item IDs whose volume is equal to the total volume:

```py
a = [50, 45, 90, 75]

b = [[1,2,3], [5,6,7], [4], [8,9]]
```

*For example, 50 would be the total volume of the items with the IDs of 1,2, and 3.*

I am currently sorting list `a` to be from smallest to largest, but I also want to arrange the order of list `b` to match its total volume. Based on the previously made lists, I want both lists to sort like this:

```py
a = [45, 50, 75, 90]

b = [[5,6,7], [1,2,3], [8,9], [4]]
```

To sort list `a`, I am writing:

`a.sort(key=lambda x: x, reverse = False)`

But I'm not sure write the code in Python for list `b` to sort based on the same pattern. I have to keep the same data structure, so both lists `a` and `b` must stay a list and list of lists, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can zip the two lists together, sort the tuples based on the `a` value, and then unzip:

```py
a = [45, 50, 75, 90]
b = [[5,6,7], [1,2,3], [8,9], [4]]

a,b = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(a, b), key = lambda x: x[0])))

print(a, b, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[45, 50, 75, 90]
[[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [8, 9], [4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()` and two list comprehensions:

```py
a = [50, 45, 90, 75]
b = [[1,2,3], [5,6,7], [4], [8,9]]

a = [x for x, _ in sorted(zip(a, b))]
b = [y for _, y in sorted(zip(a, b))]
print(a)
print(b)
```

This outputs:

```py
[45, 50, 75, 90]
[[5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3], [8, 9], [4]]
```